# Traveling with US visa with new passport with non-matching surname

Tags: visas, usa

I'm separated from my spouse I don't want to put his name on new passport which was expiring. My concern is that my old passport had surname of his and my visa is valid with his surname. Can I still travel my visa?

Comment: You can still use your old visa as long as you have documentation of your name change.